Meaning of 為時已晚
為時已晚 means it's too late.
時已晚 literally means the time is late or it's too late.
My question is what does 為 mean here? It seems excessive and unnecessary.

Most proverb are fixed in four words.  Sometimes some extra words are added just to make up four words.

i.g. 無影無蹤 ← 無影蹤,  無所不知 ← 無不知

为时 - 为时是汉语词汇，意思是从时间上看。
為時已晚 - Already too late.

为时已晚: 太晚了：表示某个时间点已经过去，无法再进行某项活动或完成某个任务。

My question is what does 為 mean here?

为 has so many meanings! This one seems to fit the bill.

(4) 表示动作行为所向，可译为“向”、“对”、“朝” [facing to;toward]
为具言所闻。——晋· 陶渊明《桃花源记》
不足为外人道。
为弟子说前代事。——清· 周容《芋老人传》

为: regarding
时: (the) time
已晚: (it is) already late
Old Motown song:
为时已晚宝宝现在为时已晚
It’s too late Baby now, it’s too late,
虽然我们真的试过了。
though we really did try to make it.
